# Is there any computational basis (in mathematical terms) for human behaviour? and if so what is the simplest one?

Tags: cognitive-science, computational-theory-of-mind

I would like to know from the experts here if there is a well known or standard set of variables that are used in computational cognitive science to quantify human behaviour.

Of course I recognize that this is a hard or nigh-impossible task to be comprehensive about behaviour, but what I am looking for is a basis (like in math - a set of vectors) of something that spans the space of human behaviour.

I am unable to really frame this better, but one other attempt would be the following:

What is the smallest set of variables that can approximately (but well enough) describe the largest space of human behaviour?

If there's an answer would be grateful to hear it, but if not, any pointers in the direction of where to look, what field to check out would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please edit your post to clarify how this is related to AI and our site? See our on-topic page. It might be obvious to you but not others. Thanks.